# How to draw an overlay from a service

Tags: java, android

My app is supposed to draw an overlay (blue light filter) at a certain time. Now I have a method called

```
private void drawOverlay()
```

Which under normal circumstances works perfectly fine. However, I want to use this method from a service, that runs in the background and is already running, so that I can draw the overlay at a certain time. In some cases this works, but sometimes I get a the following error.:-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I understand this has something to do with the `UI thread`, and I am supposed to use a `Looper` and a `handler` and I have read the documentation, but I cannot fully work out how I am supposed to do this.

Can someone please clarify this.

```
 private void drawOverlay() {
    log("drawing overlay");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        log("overlay >m checking permission");
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (permissionGranted) {
            log("permission granted");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_dimmer, null);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(view, params);
            overlayDrawn = true;
        } else {
            log("no permission");
        }
    } else {
        log("overlay drawing no permission needed (<m)");
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (permissionGranted) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_dimmer, null);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(view, params);
        }
    }
}
```

Before the service is started the app checks if it has permission to draw an overlay, that is where the `permissionGranted` boolean comes from, this is only needed if the SDK version is higher than M.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: I posted my code for drawOverlay, is that enough?